# es6 iterate object with var, let, or const?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, ecmascript-6

Traditionally, we use

```
for (var key in yourobject) {
  console.log(key, yourobject[key]);
}
```

But with es6, should I change to using `const key` or `let key` instead?

Comment: depends, var is perfectly OK in most loops, but `let` I think is the go-to :p

Comment: Using `let` rather than `var` changes the behaviour (in browsers that implement it properly), but the new behaviour is (subjectively) better, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn `const` doesn't imply that the variable is a constant or that it cannot be mutated – it is a constant *binding*, not a constant *value*

Comment: @naomik - I removed that part of my comment before you replied, but what I meant is that it *looks* weird to have `for (const key ...)` when `key` will get a series of different values. Is there a context other than a loop when a particular `const` can get different *values*? (I know if it refers to an object the object can be mutated, but that's not the same thing.)

Comment: @nnnnnn `for (const x of xs) ...` might appear strange to you, but if you have no intention of reassigning `x` (you probably don't), there's no reason to use the more permissive `let` binding; at least not one I can think of. Admittedly, I've flip-flopped between the two over the last year or so, but I've landed on `const` for almost everything. `let` signals to me that reassignment of the binding will be happening

Comment: @naomik - Yeah, I too prefer `const` to `let` except where `let` is necessary. It's just `for (const x in xs)` *looks* as if `x` is getting reassigned on each iteration, but I know really it's creating a separate `x` on each iteration not reusing the same one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with whether you're using them in a loop. Use the correct binding for whatever your program needs

- `const` bindings cannot be reassigned
- `let` bindings can be reassigned

If you do not need the ability to reassign your variables, use `const` –  it's more strict and will help protect you from accidental reassignment

If you do need the ability to reassign, you have no other choice but to use `let` (or `var`)

---

I like @jfriend's decision tree, but I might write mine like this ^_^

1. use `const`
2. if you run into a reassignment problem, use `let`
3. if you run into an out-of-scope problem, double-check you haven't made a mistake; if not, use `var`

---

> so since i'm using it in a for loop which reassigns the key in each cycle, i should use let?

No. `const` and `let` bindings are only available within the context/scope they are defined. In the case of `for` or `while` loops, the binding will only be available in the loop's body – no reassignment is taking place

```js
for (const x of [1,2,3])
  console.log(x)
//1
//2
//3
  
for (const {a} of [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}])
  console.log(a)  
//1
//2
//3

// const x and const a are not available outside of the loop
console.log(x) // ERROR: Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
console.log(a) // ERROR: Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Comment: so since i'm using it in a for loop which reassigns the key in each cycle, i should use let?

Comment: 3. If you run into an out of scope problem, double-check whether you're trying to do something illogical and if not use `var`.

Comment: @nnnnnn even better <3